# Variadic template: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, variadic-templates, argument-unpacking

I'm trying to pass multiple strings to fill a Container, but I receive this error. Using gcc 4.9.3

```
template< class T >
struct DataCompare {
    bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const
    {
        return operator<( lhs->getCode(), rhs->getCode() );
    }
};

using AggContainer = boost::container::flat_set< T, C >; 
using DataPtr      = boost::shared_ptr< BomQueueData >;
using PropertyQueueDataLess = DataCompare< DataPtr >;
using QueueDataPtrs = AggContainer< DataPtr, DataLess >;

QueueDataPtrs vector_name;

template< class Container, typename ... Args >
static void fillWithData(Container & oDataContainer, Args const & ... args)
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type::element_type QueueDataPtr;
    oDataContainer.emplace(new QueueDataPtr(args));
}

fillWithData(vector_name, x, a, b, c, d); // compiler error
```

How to solve?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And also please copy-paste the full error output (long as it might be with templates) as text into the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args` is a parameter pack, not a parameter. That's why you can't use:

```
DataContainer.emplace(new QueueDataPtr(args));
```

Instead, use

```
DataContainer.emplace(new QueueDataPtr(args...));
```

That expands the parameter pack.

Comment: @rh0x, only if I had a penny for every stupid mistake I committed :)

Comment: @Sahu ^^ how can I guarantee I'm using the move constructor? I have to define it into BomQueueData?

Comment: I think the syntax for that is `QueueDataPtr(std::forward(args)...)`

Answer (score 3):

For perfect forwarding, use a universal reference for the `args` parameter, and then forward it:

```
template< class Container, typename ... Args >
static void fillWithData(Container & oDataContainer, 
                         Args&& ... args)  // universal reference
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type::element_type QueueDataPtr;
    oDataContainer.emplace(new QueueDataPtr(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```